# Create galaxy local toolshed using Planemo

Tags: software-installation, galaxy

I tried to create [galaxy local toolshed](https://galaxyproject.org/toolshed/) using [planemo](https://github.com/galaxyproject/planemo). I used command as follows,

1. create virtual env

   ```
   virtualenv .venv; .venv/bin/activate
   ```
2. Install planemo

   ```
   pip install planemo
   ```
3. To configuring a shed account

   ```
   planemo config_init
   ```
4. Create a repository

   ```
   planemo shed_init --name=seqtk_seq \
                     --owner=planemo \
                     --description=seqtk_seq \
                     --long_description="Tool that converts FASTQ 
                                         to FASTA files using seqtk" \
                     --category="Fastq Manipulation"
   planemo shed_create --shed_target local
   ```

This produces the following error:

```
Failed to include files for [{'source': '**'}]
Problem encountered executing action for one or more repositories.
(.venv) varuna@varuna-Inspiron-15-3567:~/git/galaxy_stable/planemo
```

Comment: Hi, could you paste the text of the error instead of screenshots? It might make it easier to read and help you.

Comment: Failed to include files for [{'source': '**'}]
Problem encountered executing action for one or more repositories.

Comment: Could not update local
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9009): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/repositories?key=dc5c7cd5cf56a2f44aacf755109e63b9 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f55542b7310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)), 0 attempts left:

Comment: Try providing a project name `planemo shed_create --shed_target local someProjectName`.

Comment: I created galaxy local toolshed editing the xml files inside galaxy folder and  ran it using 9009 port. After run toolshed, I tried above mentioned command with project name.
# planemo shed_create --shed_target local /home/varuna/git/galaxy_stable

Got following error.
"description required for automatic creation or update of shed metadata"

Answer (score 1):

`--shed_target local` will only work if you're running a Galaxy toolshed on your local computer, since it's reading the `.shed.yaml` file you made with `planemo shed_init` and trying to create a repository with that name or a local (in this case) server. Planemo itself won't start a Galaxy toolshed, since it's fairly unusual for people to want to do testing involving creating local repositories. What you probably want to do instead is use `planemo test` instead. Once the planemo testing passes then use the various `shed*` commands to upload your wrapper to the toolshed or testtoolshed.